# Prove a formula for the variance of two independent random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

I tried to prove the formula , but I must have made a mistake somewhere. Here is the formula. $\xi,\eta$ - independent random variables.
$D[\xi\eta] = D\xi D\eta + (\textbf{E}\xi)^2 D\eta + (\textbf{E}\eta)^2 D\xi$
My attempt:
$D[\xi\eta] = \textbf{E}\xi^2\eta^2 - (\textbf{E}\xi\eta)^2 = \textbf{E}\xi^2\textbf{E}\eta^2 - (\textbf{E}\xi)^2\textbf{E}\eta^2 + (\textbf{E}\xi)^2\textbf{E}\eta^2  -  (\textbf{E}\xi\eta)^2 = 
\textbf{E}\eta^2(\textbf{E}\xi^2 - (\textbf{E}\xi)^2) + \textbf{E}\xi^2(\textbf{E}\eta^2 - (\textbf{E}\eta)^2) = \textbf{E}\eta^2D\xi + \textbf{E}\xi^2D\eta $
??????

Comment: I am unfamiliar with using $D$ for variance.  Have you a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line is wrong.

It should be $E\eta^2(E\xi^2-(E\xi)^2)+(E\xi)^2(E\eta^2-(E\eta^2))=E\eta^2D\xi+(E\xi)^2D\eta$.

However $E\eta^2D\xi=D\eta D\xi+(E\eta)^2D\xi$ which gives the result you are looking for.